# Gagliardo-Nirenberg-Sobolev inequality on a half-space

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, reference-request, sobolev-spaces

I'm looking for a reference about the Gagliardo-Nirenberg-Sobolev interpolation inequality on a half space $\mathbb{R}^d_+:= \lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}^d \mid x_d > 0 \rbrace$ :

Let $1 \leq p,q,r \leq \infty$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Suppose $j \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\alpha \in [0,1]$ satisfy the relations
\begin{align*}
&\dfrac{1}{p}=\dfrac{j}{d}+\left( \dfrac{1}{r}-\dfrac{m}{d} \right)\alpha+\dfrac{1-\alpha}{q},\\
&\dfrac{j}{m} \leq \alpha \leq 1,
\end{align*}
with the exception $\alpha<1$ if $m-j-d/r \in \mathbb{N}$.

Then for all $u \in \mathrm{L}^q(\mathbb{R}^d_+)$, if $\mathrm{D}^m u \in \mathrm{L}^r(\mathbb{R}^d_+)$ and if $u$ has a vanishing trace on $\partial\mathbb{R}^d_+$, then we have
$$ \Vert \mathrm{D}^j u  \Vert_{\mathrm{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^d_+)} \lesssim \Vert \mathrm{D}^m u \Vert_{\mathrm{L}^r(\mathbb{R}^d_+)} ^{\alpha} \Vert u \Vert_{\mathrm{L}^q(\mathbb{R}^d_+)}^{1-\alpha},$$
where $\lesssim$ is a universal constant.

I know that this inequality holds in the case of $\mathbb{R}^d$ or a smooth bounded domain (with a function having a vanishing trace on the boundary) but I was wondering if it also holds for a half space.

Comment: Yes. You can use an extension operator that is bounded between each Sobolev space and itself.

Comment: Ok, but with such an extension operator $P$ you get, for instance, $\Vert Pu \Vert_{\mathrm{W}^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)} \leq C \Vert u \Vert_{\mathrm{W}^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^d_+)}$, but here we need $\Vert \mathrm{D}^j Pu \Vert_{\mathrm{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^d)} \leq C \Vert \mathrm{D}^j u \Vert_{\mathrm{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^d_+)}$ for all $j \in \left\lbrace 0, \cdots k \right\rbrace$, no ?

Comment: Good point. You have to add a second lower term that vanishes only if the function vanishes.

Comment: I retract my retraction. I think if you look at the extension operator $P$ defined in Stein's book, Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions, it does satisfy the bound $\|D^jPu\|_p \le C \|D^ju\|_p$.

Comment: Ok thank you. It's a bit hidden in the proof but I think he indeed treats each derivative separately in order to show the continuity of the operator.

Comment: @SELM: I am not quite clear about the final conclusion of your question.  Yes or No?